# Como obtener la direccion de un marker en movimiento con google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

hola buenas tardes este post es requerido para solicitar su apoyo con mi código JS ya que ya obtengo la latitud y la longitud de un marker en movimiento pero nose como obtener la dirección que en este caso seria el formatted_address para obtener(calle colonia ciudad) y mandarlo a un input, les comparto mi codigo.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(vMarker, 'dragend', function (evt){
            $("#lat").val(evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(6));
            $("#lng").val(evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));
            
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar [Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) para obtener más datos a partir de la latitud y longuitud.

El código sería algo asi:

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

google.maps.event.addListener(vMarker, 'dragend', function (evt){
    const latlng = {
        lat: parseFloat(evt.latLng.lat()),
        lng: parseFloat(evt.latLng.lng()),
    };
    geocoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, (results, status) => {
        if (status === "OK") {
          if (results[0]) {
            // En results[0] hay muchos datos
            console.log(results[0].formatted_address); // dirección formateada
          } else {
            window.alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          window.alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: excelente lo voy a probar y te comento que tal :)